# Pass the current row value of aid from form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and I want to fetch the updated value of aid field from form each time a submit button is pressed. There are two submit buttons and I want the id as per the clicked row

HTML Form(it is shown dynamically with php code)

```
foreach( $results as $result ) {
$form.= '<form id="voteform" action="" method="post">';
$form.= "<input id='aid' name='aid' type='text' value='$result->aid'>";

$form.=" <input class='star' class='star' id='star5'  type='submit'  name='star5' value='5'>";
$form.=" <input class='star' class='star' id='star6'  type='submit'  name='star5' value='5'></form";
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("click",".star", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
var aidd = jQuery("#aid").val();
sentdata =({

            action: 'star',
            aid:aidd,

        })
$.post(yes.ajaxurl, sentdata, function (res) { //start of funciton
         alert(aid);
            $("#myresult").html(res);

            return false;
        } //end of function
        ,
        'json');    }); //end inner function
}); //end main function
```

php code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_star', 'star' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_star', 'star');


function star()
{

    $aid = $_POST['aid'];
echo json_encode($aid);
die();
}
```

Comment: so what is ur question/problem?

Comment: the correct aid value as per the row is not passed on pressing submit button ... kindly note that there is a for loop so there are mutliple forms and on click I want the aid of that row to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to get the **closest parent** `form` element for the `submit` button then.

Try like this:

```
var aidd = $(this).closest("form").find("#aid").val();
```

Comment: wow ... you are amazing .... can you please explain how does this stement find the closest aid... just for my knowlege and thanks

Comment: ok great ... I just read your words ... so this finds the closest form with #aid in it .. wow ... thanks .. I've maked it as complete

Comment: closest("form") gives you the parent form element of the submit button, then you find child element in the form you found with id `aid`. glad it helped u.